# Variables between factories in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently learning angular and have hit a roadblock.
The second factory (shown below) makes an http request like this: http://example.com/api/get_post/?**post_id=7129**&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');

I want the post ID to be a variable. So depending on which blog title is clicked, I can pass the correct variable into that http request.

In other words, I guess I want to take a result from the first factory (blogAPIservice) and use it in the second factory.

Makes sense??

```
<!-- FACTORIES -->

angular.module('blogApp.services',[])
.factory('blogAPIservice',function($http) {
    var blogAPI = [];
    var blogs = $http.jsonp('http://example.com/api/get_recent_posts/?count=10&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
    blogs.success(function(data) {
        $.each(data.posts, function(i, blog) {
            var fromNow = moment(blog.date).fromNow();
            blogAPI.push({
                url: blog.url,
                title: blog.title,
                excerpt: blog.excerpt,
                date : fromNow,
                id: blog.id
            })
        });
    });
    var factory = {};
    factory.getBlogs = function () {
        return blogAPI;
    };
    return factory;
})
.factory('singlePostService',function($http) {
    var singleAPI = [];
    var postID = '7129';
    var singlePost = $http.jsonp('http://example.com/api/get_post/?post_id=7129&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
    singlePost.success(function(data) {
            singleAPI.push({
                title: data.post.title,
                content: data.post.content
            })
    });
    var factory = {};
    factory.getSinglePost = function () {
        return singleAPI;
    };
    return factory;
})
```

And here are the controllers:

```
angular.module('blogApp.controllers', [])
.controller('resultsController',function($scope, blogAPIservice) {
    $scope.keywordFilter = null;
    $scope.blogs = [];

    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.blogs = blogAPIservice.getBlogs();
    }

    function grabID() {
        $(this).attr('rel');

    }

})
.controller('singlePostController',function($scope, singlePostService) {
    $scope.keywordFilter = null;
    $scope.singlePost = [];

    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.singlePost = singlePostService.getSinglePost();
    }

})
```

And finally the markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="blog in blogs">
     <a href="#/single">{{ blog.title }}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Can't you just inject your other service in?

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the first service into the second one like this:

```
.factory('singlePostService',function($http, blogAPIservice) {
    //Do something with blogAPIservice
}
```

For more information about depenency injection read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)